# Cognex Vision Suite (ViDi) - Remove part for a image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, vision, cognex

I'm new to cognex world, so if anyone can help I will be thankful.

I have a image, how can I remove a Region of a Image?

So my ROI is a box, but there is a smaller box inside of that bigger box that is not important. So my ROI will be the bigger box less the smaller box.

I tried filters, but filter a new image with the size of the region (ROI filter).

How can I do this?

Comment: nobody's watching or using the cognex tag. you'd have better luck contacting the company's customer support, or finding some forum they run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the mask to ignore a part of the image. Some tools allow different "uses" of the mask so make sure it fits what you need.
For example, segmentation tools (red tools) can use the masked region as an extra channel of the image.